# Eliminating a certain part of a logfile before loading to table in Pentaho using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have several logfiles that need to be loaded into a table. However, the first three lines have to be omitted automatically without me having to remove them.

I have used a text file input where all the data from the log file has been put into a single column under the name Field 1.

These are the first four line which is the first four rows.

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-10-25 22:30:02
#Fields: date time s-computername s-ip....
```

As you can see above, the first four lines have to be omitted  and I have to load data after '#Fields:'. Is there a way to do it using Javascript in Pentaho?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use step called modified java-script step , and according to your need you can write a code and achieve your desired result..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But the problem I have is with the code that needs to be written. Any suggestions about the code?

Comment: lines are specified with softwares , version ect..
so differentiate such words and store it into particular field, and then remove the fields which you don't want to display,i mean just pass the required fields to the next step.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. It would be very helpful if you can suggest a logic to do the same. The lines that are to be written, I'll take care. But I need to have a logic that eliminates that particular part of the log file alone. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to filter out all lines that start with #, as being comments.

You can achieve much faster results by using a Filter Rows step, with a condition "not starts with". The Javascript step is too slow, I recommend avoiding it if there's any other option available.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply start reading text file from the 5th lines? In the Content tab of the text input step you can set the *Number of header lines*. Put 4 in the input.